# Why is linearity of integration important?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, soft-question, lebesgue-integral

From a conceptual point of view why is the linearity of integration so important?  What does it represent geometrically besides making calculations simpler?

Comment: for example it makes integration a linear functional acting on the vector space of functions. this makes it possible to apply big parts of the machinery of linear algebra to integration. furthermore integrations generalizes summation. And summation is linear. therefore we want integration also to be linear

Comment: Think intergral ~ area and area is additive and scaleable.